# Glyph origin of component 龺?

Tags: characters, glyph-origin

Recently after I've happened to come across the component 倝 (gàn; sunrise, dawn) (**Baxter-Sagart OC**: *[k]ˤar-s),  I was curious about the left component, or 龺, since I've also seen this component in other characters such as 朝 (cháo; dynasty/zhāo; morning) (**Baxter-Sagart OC**: *m-taw or *taw) and 翰 (hàn; writing brush, pen, pencil) (**Baxter-Sagart OC**: *[g]ˤar, *[g]ˤar-s or *m-kˤar-s).

However though when looking up the origin for this component, I came across three possible explanations.

The ones being are:

- Pictograph of the sun (日) rising through the grass (originally either two or four 屮 components, now written as two 十 components).
- Abbreviation of 倝.
- Variation of 卓.

I think I understand that 龺 is not, in terms of etymology, related to 卓 since im assuming it is grouped that way since 卓 looks similar to 龺.

So maybe if I can get some clarification here, what is the true glyph origin for the component 龺? Is this component just an abbreviation of 倝 or is this a pictograph character?

(Also just a note, I've added the Baxter-Sagart old Chinese pronunciations just to see if any characters with that exact component is related at all to each other and looks like both 朝 and 翰 seem to not be related at all. However though both 倝 and 翰 seem to share similar pronunciations. I'm still a bit confused though on the usage of the component here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「龺」 is a [regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) shape that appears multiple times by coincidence. There is not really a "glyph origin of 「龺」" to speak of:

- 「倝」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[k]ˤar-s/**, *sunrise*) is comprised of semantic [「昜」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=6328) (*bright*) and phonetic [「㫃」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=35898) (**/*qarʔ/**).

  <kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image: 倝]
  羌鐘
  [集成158](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=158&jgwfl=)</kbd>

  This form is an illustrative structure for 「倝」. There is no individual component like 「龺」; the thing that looks like 「早」 in 「倝」 is a graphical corruption of 「昜」, and the thing that looks like 「十」 (*shape of a flagpole*) and 「人」 (*shape of a flag or banner*) forms the picture that 「㫃」 represents.

  「倝」 is a very common phonetic component, such as in 「翰」, 「乾」， and 「幹」. It is also a phonetic component in 「韓」 (originally 「」), but here, the flag banner shape was left out.
- 「朝」 (*morning*) is a picture of a *(rising) sun* [「日」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=136) side-by-side with a *(setting) moon* [「月」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=138) among *plants and trees* (multiple [「屮」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5413) or [「木」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=139)).

  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image: 朝]
  [後](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.3.8
  [合集33130](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33130&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
  甲
  [image: 朝]
  [佚](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)292
  [合集29092](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=29092&jgwfl=)</kbd>

  「龺」 is not an individual component here, but rather an arbitrary grouping of 「日」 and the *plants and trees* (abbreviated into 「十十」).
- The ["variant of 「卓」"](https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwNDM5#13) is just a very rare shape change. 「卓」 is a picture of a *child* [「子」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=45) with a tag on the child's head.

  <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  金
  [image: 卓]
  九年衛鼎
  [集成2831](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=2831&jgwfl=)</kbd>

  「子」 was later corrupted into 「早」, and in 「」, the tag is written as 「十」.

---

**References**:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》